# Prove $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{27}\leq\int_0^1\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\leq\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{132}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to prove that this is true:

$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{27}\leq\int_0^1\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\leq\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{132}$$

Only idea I have is trying to use Darboux sums to somehow reach this but it's probably a bad idea as I don't see how to reach these numbers with Darboux sums.

I'm looking for the **smallest possible hint**, so please don't post a solution for now.

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Teeny tiny hint: I'm guessing here that $1/27$ is $\frac13\cdot\frac19$ and that $1/132$ is $\frac1{12}\cdot\frac1{11}$. The fact that you have a sum of terms of the form $\frac{(-1)^na_n}{2n+1}$ suggests some approaches...

Comment: Hint: $$
1 - x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} - \frac{{x^3 }}{6} < e^{ - x}  < 1 - x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} - \frac{{x^3 }}{6} + \frac{{x^4 }}{{24}}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

By Taylor-Lagrange formula, we have for $ x>0 $,

$$e^{-x}= 1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}e^{-c}$$

with $ 0< c < x \le 1$.

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx = \frac 23-\frac 25+...$$